# GL_LINE_STRIP - Using Textures ? iOS GLKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

Is it possible in OpenGL ES 2.0 to use GL_LINE_STRIP to draw a shape and then apply a texture to that shape ?

E.g if I draw a triangle can I then apply a triangle texture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GL_LINE_STRIP` draws only lines. If you want polygons filled in (whether with color, lighting, or texturing), you need one of the solid polygon modes: `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

If you want to both fill and stroke your polygons, you'll need two draw calls, one with each mode. And if you're using depth testing, you'll probably want to look into `glPolygonOffset` to avoid z-fighting.

Comment: Thanks - good idea re the double draw. So this is the only way to draw and fill point to point shapes ?